# How can i retrieve more than 50 results while querying python youtube api?

Tags: python, api, youtube, gdata

Hi can increase the number of results on youtube video metadata retrieval when searching based on a keyword.  Max number of results provided is 50, i want to increase it more than that for analysis purpose.

Comment: Is that limit set in place by the API?

Comment: Can we see your code?  From what I can see, you can set the maximum number of results

Comment: Yes the limit is set up by API as 50. Can't we get that increased ?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, as per the attribute max_results i have set statement as:
query.max_results = 50 , which is fine but when i give more than 50 it gives me error saying max_results should be within 0 to 50. I need to extract bulk of results for my research. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I had to look at the [Reference Guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#max-resultssp) for the API.   It seems 50 is the maximum.:

> The max-results parameter specifies the maximum number of results that
>   should be included in the result set. This parameter works in
>   conjunction with the start-index parameter to determine which results
>   to return. For example, to request the second set of 10 results – i.e.
>   results 11-20 – set the max-results parameter to 10 and the
>   start-index parameter to 11. The default value of this parameter is
>   25, and the maximum value is 50. However, for displaying lists of
>   videos, we recommend that you set the max-results parameter to 10.

Comment: I have tried the above code and the same limit stands here too. when you change the Max results to more than 50 it throws you the red error :(

Comment: This most likely won't work, but trying making the `max-results` 50 and the `start-index` 51.  Does that work?

Comment: Nope!! No difference just fifty results after making the start_index as 51 also.

Comment: But are those the same 50?  Did you check that?

Comment: They Are the same ones.

Comment: Then as far as the API goes, there isn't a way to do this.  Maybe they will update the API some day so that this is possible.  |=^/

Comment: I had requested for an enhancement then they replied me as:"You can get up to 500 results in V2 or V3 of the API. Review the relevant docs and look around for "paging" or "pagination"... the info is there. Good luck!"  But i am not able to get any idea how to use pageToken.
I mean how to give it the value as:
pageToken = nextPageToken, how do i do that???

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/pagination   Did you look at this?